# Making PHP GET parameters look like directories

Tags: url-rewriting

I am trying to make it so:

`http://foo.foo/?parameter=value`
"converts" to
`http://foo.foo/value`

Thanks.

Comment: Google -> .htaccess + mod_rewrite tutorial.

Comment: Please indicate your web server, as this is a web server question *not* a question about PHP.  If you happen to be using IIS, you can see this link for info (as everyone else is sharing mod_rewrite info) - http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're running on Apache, this code in .htaccess works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /index.php?parameter=$1
```

Depending on your site structure you may have to ad a few rules though.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling `mod_rewrite` on your Apache server and using `.htaccess` rules to redirect requests to a controller file.

.htaccess

```
# Enable rewrites
RewriteEngine On
# The following two lines skip over other HTML/PHP files or resources like CSS, Javascript and image files 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# test.php is our controller file
RewriteRule ^.*$ test.php [L]
```

test.php

```
$args = explode('/', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']);  // REDIRECT_URL is provided by Apache when a URL has been rewritten
array_shift($args);
$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($args); $i++) {
    $k = $args[$i];
    $v = ++$i < count($args) ? $args[$i] : null;
    $data[$k]= $v;
}
print_r($data);
```

Accessing the url http://localhost/abc/123/def/456 will output the following:

```
Array
(
    [abc] => 123
    [def] => 456
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache, the following tutorials are epically helpful:

1. [.htaccess part one](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php)
2. [.htaccess part two](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

The second tutorial has your answer. Prepare to dig deep into a dungeon called `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

Use mod rewrite rules if you are using Apache. This is better and secure way to make a virtual directory.