# Making php handle get URI's like symfony

Tags: php

I am starting a project that is too small to use a framework for, but I would like to make the uri look like how symfony has them.

e.g.

example.net/directory/var/value/

instead of

example.net/directory?var=value

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Doh, sorry for posting this... I found a way to do this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351806/making-php-get-parameters-look-like-directories

Comment: Look for "url rewrite", if you are using Apache, look for "mod_rewrite".

Comment: Symfony2's Routing is a standalone component: [link](https://github.com/symfony/Routing). Also check out [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), a microframework on top of Symfony2 components (including the routing).

Comment: Thing is, I don't want any controllers at all. I only have a few pages that I have to link to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the keyword you have to look for is: **url rewrite**

here is a simple example
make a file named .htaccess into your root

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /directory.php?var=$1&value=$2 [NC]
```

and that happens:

```
 http://domain.com/directory/AAA/123  => /directory.php?var=AAA&value=123
```

more over here: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: Is there any way to make it like so...
example.com/foo => example.com/index.php?variable=foo
I cant get your code to work without putting index.php in the uri

Comment: that is just semantics eighther you do everything in index.php or you split it by function.

Comment: gah I guess I could just stick actual directories there :-/